# JDBC oracle connection error: ORA-12519, TNS:no appropriate service handler found

Tags: java, multithreading, jdbc, oracle12c, ojdbc

In my project I am using jdbc to connect to a oracle 12c instance in a multi-threading environment, earlier we had an oracle 9i instance and we were using ojdbc6 and it was working perfectly but we receltly got this oracle 12c instance which gave following error at JDBC connection point.

java.sql.SQLException: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12519, TNS:no appropriate service handler found

```
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:774)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.connect(PhysicalConnection.java:688)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:39)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:691)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
```

So I thought it may be because of the older driver version that we had, so I incorporated ojdbc8 which I found over the internet to be compatible with 12 but the above error is still there. My JDK version is 1.8.

I'd appreciate any input on resolving this issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi does this make sense jdbc:oracle:thin:@FullComputerName:PORT:SID                    username="Username"; password="password";                                       
con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);

Answer (score 0):

Sid. I think the bug occurred dut to the Oracle initialization parameter setting problem.
Please use the command line as below:

```
SQL > SHOW the PARAMETER of the SESSION
------------------------------------ ----------- ------------------------------
java_max_sessionspace_size integer 0
java_soft_sessionspace_limit integer 0
license_max_sessions integer 0
license_sessions_warning integer 0
session_cached_cursors integer 50
session_max_open_files integer 10
sessions integer 600
shared_server_sessions integer
```

the other command line:

```
SQL> SHOW PARAMETER PROCESS
NAME TYPE VALUE
------------------------------------ ----------- ------------------------------
aq_tm_processes integer 0
db_writer_processes integer 2
gcs_server_processes integer 2
global_txn_processes integer 1
job_queue_processes integer 1000
log_archive_max_processes integer 4
processes integer 150
```

According to the Oracle documentation, SESSIONS and the TRANSACTIONS of the initialization parameters should be derived from the PROCESSES, according to the default setting SESSIONS = 1.1 + 5 by the PROCESSES.

SESSIONS currently set up to 600, and the PROCESSES of setting has not changed, still for 150, led to too much user session to connect to the Oracle, Oracle do not have enough background PROCESSES to support these SESSIONS.

The direct solution is set the appropriate the PROCESSES.